# Let cleveref always get the original environment name in a multi-language document

Tags: babel, cleveref

Look at the following example, here I'm writing in two languages using `babel`. The name for the theorem environment (`\theoremname`) automatically changes with the language. Notice that the names are `Théorème 1` and `Theorem 2`.

When I cite them, since cleveref only reads the current value of `\theoremname`, I get `Theorem 1 and Theorem 2` in English context, and `Théorème 1 et Théorème 2` in French context. However, I'd like the result to always be `Théorème 1` and `Theorem 2`, no matter the context.

Is there any way to achieve this, without having to define separate environments for English and French?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{\theoremname}
\def\theoremname{}

\usepackage[french,english]{babel}
\addto{\captionsenglish}{\def\theoremname{Theorem}}
\addto{\captionsfrench}{\def\theoremname{Théorème}}

\crefname{theorem}{\theoremname}{\theoremname}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{french}
\begin{theorem}\label{thm:french}
    French.
\end{theorem}
\cref{thm:french} et \cref{thm:english}

\selectlanguage{english}
\begin{theorem}\label{thm:english}
    English.
\end{theorem}
\cref{thm:french} and \cref{thm:english}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I’m pretty sure you would need to define two different environments. However, you could use `iflang` to select which of those two environments to create, based on the current language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define different theorem environments, sharing the same numbering, and create an environment that will select the appropriate one for the current language.

```
\documentclass[french,english]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{iflang}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\addto{\captionsenglish}{\def\theoremname{Theorem}}
\addto{\captionsfrench}{\def\theoremname{Théorème}}

\newcounter{theorem}
\newtheorem{theoremEN}[theorem]{\foreignlanguage{english}{\theoremname}}
\newtheorem{theoremFR}[theorem]{\foreignlanguage{french}{\theoremname}}

\crefname{theoremEN}{Theorem}{Theorems}
\crefname{theoremFR}{Théorème}{Théorèmes}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{theorem}{O{}}%
  {\IfLanguageName{french}%
    {\begin{theoremFR}[#1]}%
    {\begin{theoremEN}[#1]}}%
  {\IfLanguageName{french}%
    {\end{theoremFR}}%
    {\end{theoremEN}}}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{french}
\begin{theorem}\label{thm:french}
    French.
\end{theorem}
\cref{thm:french} et \cref{thm:english}

\selectlanguage{english}
\begin{theorem}[in English]\label{thm:english}
    English.
\end{theorem}
\cref{thm:french} and \cref{thm:english}

\end{document}
```

[image: Theorem and Théorème]

Answer (score 2):

**LAST EDIT: A full automated way:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newtheorem{theorem}{\theoremname}
\def\theoremname{}

\usepackage[french,english]{babel}
\addto{\captionsenglish}{\def\theoremname{Theorem}}
\addto{\captionsfrench}{\def\theoremname{Théorème}}

\crefname{theorem}{\theoremname}{\theoremname}

\let\oldlabel\label
\def\label#1{\oldlabel{#1}\edef\lnm{\languagename}\oldlabel{\lnm:#1}}
\let\oldcref\cref
\makeatletter
\def\cref#1{\ifcsname r@\languagename:#1\endcsname\oldcref{#1}\else{\setsepchar{,}\readlist*\langlist{\bbl@loaded}\foreachitem\itm\in\langlist{{\ifcsname r@\itm:#1\endcsname\select@language{\itm}\oldcref{#1}}\fi}}\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{french}
\begin{theorem}\label{thm:1}
    French.
\end{theorem}
\cref{thm:1} et \cref{thm:2}

\selectlanguage{english}
\begin{theorem}\label{thm:2}
    English.
\end{theorem}
\cref{thm:1} and \cref{thm:2}

\end{document}
```

Edit:

An automated way:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{xstring}
\newtheorem{theorem}{\theoremname}
\def\theoremname{}

\usepackage[french,english]{babel}
\addto{\captionsenglish}{\def\theoremname{Theorem}}
\addto{\captionsfrench}{\def\theoremname{Théorème}}

\crefname{theorem}{\theoremname}{\theoremname}

\let\oldlabel\label
\def\label#1{\def\mlb{#1}\iflanguage{french}{\oldlabel{#1}\oldlabel{french:#1}}{\oldlabel{#1}\oldlabel{english:#1}}}
\let\oldcref\cref
\makeatletter
\def\cref#1{\def\mlb{#1}\ifcsname r@french:#1\endcsname{\selectlanguage{french}\oldcref{#1}}\else{\selectlanguage{english}\oldcref{#1}}\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{french}
\begin{theorem}\label{thm:1}
    French.
\end{theorem}
\cref{thm:1} et \cref{thm:2}

\selectlanguage{english}
\begin{theorem}\label{thm:2}
    English.
\end{theorem}
\cref{thm:1} and \cref{thm:2}

\end{document}
```

Old answer:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{xstring}
\newtheorem{theorem}{\theoremname}
\def\theoremname{}

\usepackage[french,english]{babel}
\addto{\captionsenglish}{\def\theoremname{Theorem}}
\addto{\captionsfrench}{\def\theoremname{Théorème}}

\crefname{theorem}{\theoremname}{\theoremname}

\def\mcref#1{\def\mlb{#1}\IfSubStr{#1}{engl}{{\selectlanguage{english}\cref{#1}}}{{\selectlanguage{french}\cref{#1}}}}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{french}
\begin{theorem}\label{thm:french}
    French.
\end{theorem}
\mcref{thm:french} et \mcref{thm:english}

\selectlanguage{english}
\begin{theorem}\label{thm:english}
    English.
\end{theorem}
\mcref{thm:french} and \mcref{thm:english}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just add the word `engl` in every label of english environment and use `\mcref` command (I added the package `xstring` in your preamble)

Comment: The edit doesn't require the above comment